# Angular Material form-field Label Font Color And Size

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am trying in Angular Material 6, to make the caption of form-field a little bigger and darker when the field is filled with input text and focus is lost.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add this to your global CSS file `style.scss` :

```css
.mat-form-field-appearance-legacy.mat-form-field-can-float.mat-form-field-should-float .mat-form-field-label:not(.mat-empty):not(.mat-form-field-empty) {
  // color
  // scale or font-size
}
```

To achieve that, I simply inspected the element, took the classes for when it was empty, the classes for when it was not empty, and made the selector accordingly.

Remember to do it in your global CSS file, not in a component's file, because the view for components is encapsulated by default (which means the style is encapsulated too) and the style won't be applied.

Comment: I made a selector mistake, sorry. But otherwise, it works, [as you can see here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nrehng?file=styles.css)

Comment: Thanks, It's working now when user starts typing in the field. Is it possible to achieve the effects only when user leaves the field.

Comment: Sure, as I told you inspect the element and see the HTML structure. You will need to find the input and make a CSS selector with `:not(:focus)`. Since I'm only here to help and not to code for you, I'll let you do this on your own !

Comment: Great,... Thank you very much

Comment: This addresses the color/darker side of the question, but does not address the size part.  Any attempt to adjust the size using this method doesn't work.  It seems the size is altered via a transform/animation.